# Thingspeak MATLAB analysis

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi3, iot

I am using `thingspeak` platform with my `pi3` for home automation. I have successfully sent and received data from my board to the channel. However, I am not able to properly understand the MATLAB analysis tutorial supported on the site.

https://in.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/analyze-your-data.html

1. I am unable to understand what and why `readchId` should be given here and 
   what is the job of MATLAB analysis.
2. if the MATLAB analysis is to write my received data to channel and then use MATLAB visualize to display it using readchId. what purpose does the `readchId` in MATLAB analysis part solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThingSpeak allows you to send data from your IoT device to a ThingSpeak channel, and then to use apply various ThingSpeak "apps" to those channels: these can perform various actions based on the channel data (like tweeting, or sending a message to some other web service), or they can perform analytics, or create visualisations, on the channel data. These analytics and visualisation apps are implemented in MATLAB code, and run on ThingSpeak.

The tutorial you're looking at reads in data from one channel (ThingSpeak 12397, which receives weather data), does some analysis on it to calculate the dew point from the temperature and humidity, and then writes it out to another channel and visualizes it.

`readChId` in the tutorial is the ID of the channel you are reading from (12397), and `writeChId` is the ID of the channel you are writing to (677 as an example, but replace with your own channel number).

Comment: Thankyou for the response. My question may be was unclear. For the MATLAB analysis part i replaced the readchId with my channel id.  but i seem to get error. so i was confused what does the readchId does.                                     this is the given error.                                                                          "Error using Temperature calculation (line 6)
Error using thingSpeakRead
Specify a valid read API key, or make the channel public to avoid specifying the read API key."

Comment: Here's my read api line " [temp,time] = thingSpeakRead(readChId,'Fields',1,'NumPoints',20,'OutputFormat','table'); "      the parameters do not have any read api key value as such.

Comment: Is your channel public? If not, then you need to get a Read API key for that channel, and then add extra arguments in your call to `thingSpeakRead`. `...'OutputFormat’, ‘table’, ‘ReadKey’, ‘PutYourAPIKeyHere’)`.

Comment: @Rohit If the answer has helped, please accept it by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.